# using Core motion for tracking sleep

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I'm trying to track sleep in my app using CoreMotion.

In the Lark app they [write](https://support.lark.com/hc/en-us/articles/211993887-Why-isn-t-lark-recording-my-sleep-correctly-)

> Sleep is computed by the last time you touch your phone before sleeping until you first use it when waking up.

So i want to implement sleep tracking the same way Lark does.

1. Can i use CoreMotion in background?
2. How would i know if it is the last or first touch?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look into `CMMotionActivityManager` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionactivitymanager) though I’m not sure that would be precise enough for your needs. You would probably need to add some filtering (e.g. a period where the device is `stationary` for several hours, possibly overlapping hours that would be considered night time).

Comment: @ilan Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

1. use some of Extended Runtime Sessions for forcing app to work at the background for some time: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions ;
2. use CMSensorRecorder https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmsensorrecorder to record and get CoreMotion's historical data.